# How to auto cropping the image from 100% to 0% without resizing itself

Tags: crop, image-resizing, object-fit

I didn't know how to put images on there so that we need to assume that instead of photo, I create a styled div. Let's assume that the `Photo1` (`background: blue`) is the Original Photo while `Photo2` (`background: red`|) is the Edited Photo. I want my project that if the user clicks the "Start" button, the original photo will gradually replace by Edited Photo pixel by pixel. Similar to the code I made. But the difference is that when the photo is placed, the photo also resizes from `width: 100%` to `width: 0px`. I want to crop the original photo pixel by pixel while the edited photo gradually revealed pixel by pixel also without resizing the photo. If you didn't understand what I need, my project is like the site https://remove.bg .. If you upload on that site, I love the feature converting the images from with BG to without BG then the animations are. .... replacing the photo with BG to photo without BG pixel by pixel. I research related in `object-fit` but I didn't expert on that kind of CSS. Hope you help me.

Here's my code

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Page title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<button>Start</button>
    <div class="Handler">
<div class="Photo1"></div> 
<div class="Photo2"></div>   
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.Handler{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 80%;
    height: 400px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.Photo1{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
    transition: 1.5s;
}
.Photo2{
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    transition: 1.5s;
}
button{
    width: 60%;
    border: none;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**JS:**

```
let a = document.querySelector("button"),
b = document.querySelector(".Photo1"),
c = document.querySelector(".Photo2");

a.addEventListener("click", function(){
b.style.width = "0px";
c.style.width = "100%"; 

setTimeout(function(){
c.style.width = "0px";
b.style.width = "100%";    
}, 3000);      
});
```

**PS:** I used my mobile device as of now to write this question, I hope others make a Code Snippet on my code. And if you Desktop User, please resize your screen to smaller width like 600px.

Comment: Although my question or title are many similars but the body of my project that I want is not same for them

Comment: Hi @nullqube, can you waste your time to provide your answer in my question? I understand a little bit in your comment because I expert in ```transfrom: translate()``` but the only problem is where/when I can start to code?

Comment: sorry I was wrong then, here are some link that can be useful: https://orangeable.com/css/before-and-after-image-slider.  https://www.codehim.com/vanilla-javascript/before-after-image-slider-in-vanilla-javascript/. but these are with slider, do the slider thing with js so make it look automated...